# SSAS OLAP cube processing failed

Tags: postgresql, ssas, olap, cube

In recent months I faced a problem regarding daily automatic proccessing of our olap cube model.
And the main problem is that this error message appears irregularly. That is, during the day, sometimes the processing is successful, sometimes an error crashes after 10 minutes

The error message goes as follows:

> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaException: The JSON DDL request
> failed with the following error: Failed to execute XMLA. Error
> returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] PostgreSQL:
> Exception while reading from stream.OLE DB or ODBC error:
> [DataSource.Error] PostgreSQL: Exception while reading from
> stream.OLE DB or ODBC error: The command has been
> canceled..'..   at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForSoapFault(XmlReader
> reader XmlaResult xmlaResult Boolean throwIfError)   at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForError(XmlReader
> reader XmlaResult xmlaResult Boolean throwIfError)   at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean
> endReceivalIfException Boolean readSession Boolean
> readNamespaceCompatibility)   at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessageAndReturnResult(String&
> result Boolean skipResult)   at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.ExecuteStatement(String
> statement String properties String& result Boolean
> skipResult Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)   at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.Execute(String command
> String properties String& result Boolean skipResult
> Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)   at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.ExecuteStatement(String
> stmt StatementType stmtType Boolean withResults String
> properties String parameters Boolean
> restrictionListElement String discoverType String
> catalog)   at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.SendCommand(String
> command Boolean withResults String properties)   at
> OlapEvent(SCH_STEP* pStep SUBSYSTEM* pSubSystem
> SUBSYSTEMPARAMS* pSubSystemParams Boolean fQueryFlag)

I have tried to set various timeouts: RemoteQueryTimeout (from 600 to bigger numbers like 2000 or even 0 for no timeout), ExternalCommandTimeout, ExternalConnectionTimeou, ForceCommitTimeout

Nothing helped and the error is still here

Has anyone faced that kind of problem? To be honest, I no longer know what the problem is and how it can be solved

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's making SOAP requests over the XmlaClient. The timeout could be client-side (Analysis Server's ExternalConnectionTimeout or ExternalCommandTimeout values), or it could be server-side - Postgres? You may need to look at the web hosting configuration on the target server to see what timeout controls are available and increase the appropriate request timeout(s).

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering @AlwaysLearning. In fact, I did try both changing ExternalConnectionTimeout (from 60 to 0 and 5000 now) or ExternalCommandTimeout (from 3600 to 0 and then to 5000 now), but still nothing helped. About Posgresql, as our programmer said there is no timeouts for long running queries. Maybe there are other solutions or its all about finding right timeout for ExternalConnectionTimeout andExternalCommandTimeout values?

Comment: Additionally, can you please specify where to find  "web hosting configuration"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. The solution was to add `“commandTimeout”:”PT1H”` for 1 hour timeout as a [condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWlVk.png) while connecting to database